# StackLayout on pressed event

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I have a view in my `StackLayout`. I want to make an effect so that when the user presses on the `StackLayout` the background changes color, and then reverts the color back when the user releases his/her finger, for a "flash" effect.

I was advised that since views don't have an "on pressed" event, I would have to use a custom renderer. But I don't know how to make a custom renderer for a `StackLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a `CustomRenderer` to have a "on pressed" event on your `StackLayout`, you can use `TapGestureRecognizer` instead.

```
<StackLayout>
...
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" />
  </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

You can read more about `GestureRecognizers` in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap).

P.S.: If you really need to react to "finger release" than you might need an [Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction) or a [CustomRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).